# Performance of Foldable's default methods

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I've been exploring the [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) class and also the the [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) class.

Firstly, lets say I want to fold over a list of the Monoid [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First). Like so:

```
x :: [First a]

fold? mappend mempty x
```

Then I assume in this case the most appropriate fold would be `foldr`, as `mappend` for [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) is lazy in it's second argument.

Conversely, for [`Last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Last) we'd want to `foldl'` (or just `foldl` I'm not sure).

Now moving away from lists, I've defined a simple binary tree like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data BinaryTree a where
  BinaryTree :: BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
  Leaf :: a -> BinaryTree a
```

And I've made it [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) with the most straightforward definition:

```
instance Foldable BinaryTree where
  foldMap f (BinaryTree left right) = 
    (foldMap f left) `mappend` (foldMap f right)
  foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
```

As [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) defines `fold` as simply `foldMap id` we can now do:

```
x1 :: BinaryTree (First a)
fold x1 

x2 :: BinaryTree (Last a)
fold x2
```

Assuming our BinaryTree is balanced, and there's not many `Nothing` values, these operations should take `O(log(n))` time I believe.

But [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) also defines a whole lot of default methods like `foldl`, `foldl'`, `foldr` and `foldr'` based on `foldMap`.

These default definitions seem to be implemented by composing a bunch of functions, wrapped in a Monoid called [`Endo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo), one for each element in the collection, and then composing them all.

For the purpose of this discussion I am not modifying these default definitions.

So lets now consider:

```
x1 :: BinaryTree (First a)
foldr mappend mempty x1 

x2 :: BinaryTree (Last a)
foldl mappend mempty x2
```

Does running these retain `O(log(n))` performance of the ordinary `fold`? (I'm not worried about constant factors for the moment). Does laziness result in the tree not needing to be fully traversed? Or will the default definitions of `foldl` and `foldr` require an entire traversal of the tree?

I tried to go though the algorithm step by step (much like they did on the [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') article) but I ended up completely confusing myself as this is a bit more complex as it involves an interaction between [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) and [`Endo`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl').

So what I'm looking for is an explanation of why (or why not) the default definition of say `foldr`, would only take `O(log(n))` time on a balanced binary tree like above. A step by step example like what's from the [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') article would be really helpful, but I understand if that's too difficult, as I totally confused myself attempting it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think `fold x2` will in fact be O(n). When walking left-to-right across a binary tree, you have to look at all of the elements to find the last non-`Nothing`. Plugging in `Last` doesn't magically make the traversal change direction. Folding a [`Reverse (BinaryTree (First a))`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Reverse.html) on the other hand should get you the same answer in O(n)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I guess that the original `O(log n)` bound does not depend on the tree being balanced, but only on how many `Nothing`s you find before hitting a `Just`.

Comment: PS you can [derive Foldable](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#deriving-typeable) to save you some boilerplate

Comment: In fact, thinking about it further, O(log(n)) is only the _best case_ for `fold x1`. If you're looking for the first `Just` in a tree of `Nothing`s you have to inspect them all. I would describe all of these functions as having O(n) complexity

Comment: Not an answer, but note that some defaults (e.g., for `foldr` and `foldl`) are quite good, others (e.g., for `sum` and `maximum`) are pretty lousy.

Comment: For the purpose of the question assume no "Nothing's" and balanced. If either of these aren't true you of course can get O(n) performance regardless of the algorithm (eg if the tree is n deep or there's all Nothing's and you have to check them all)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has O(log(n)) best case performance.

`Endo` is a wrapper around (a -> a) kind of functions that:

```
instance Monoid (Endo a) where
  mempty = Endo id
  Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```

And the default implementation of `foldr` in Data.Foldable:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z
```

The definition of `.` (function composition) in case:

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Endo is defined by newtype constructor, so it only exists at compile stage, not run-time.
`#.` operator changes the type of it's second operand and discard the first.
The newtype constructor and `#.` operator guarantee that you can ignore the wrapper when considering performance issues.

So the default implementation of `foldr` can be reduced to:

```
-- mappend = (.), mempty = id from instance Monoid (Endo a)
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = foldMap f t z
```

For your `Foldable BinaryTree`:

```
foldr f z t
  = foldMap f t z
  = case t of
    Leaf a -> f a z
    -- what we care
    BinaryTree l r -> ((foldMap f l) . (foldMap f r)) z
```

The default lazy evaluation in Haskell is ultimately simple, there are just two rules:

1. function application first
2. evaluate the arguments from left to right if the values matter

That makes it easy to trace the evaluation of the last line of the code above:

```
  ((foldMap f l) . (foldMap f r)) z
= (\z -> foldMap f l (foldMap f r z)) z
= foldMap f l (foldMap f r z)
-- let z' = foldMap f r z
= foldMap f l z' -- height 1
-- if the branch l is still not a Leaf node
= ((foldMap f ll) . (foldMap f lr)) z'
= (\z -> foldMap f ll (foldMap f lr)) z'
= foldMap f ll (foldMap f lr z')
-- let z'' = foldMap f lr z'
= foldMap f ll z'' -- height 2
```

The right branch of the tree is never expanded before the left has been fully expanded, and it goes one level higher after an O(1) operation of function expansion and application, therefore when it reached the left-most Leaf node:

```
= foldMap f leaf@(Leaf a) z'heightOfLeftMostLeaf
= f a z'heightOfLeftMostLeaf
```

Then `f` looks at the value `a` and decides to ignore its second argument (like what `mappend` will do to `First` values), the evaluation short-circuits, results O(height of the left-most leaf), or O(log(n)) performance when the tree is balanced.

`foldl` is all the same, it's just `foldr` with `mappend` flipped i.e. O(log(n)) best case performance with `Last`.

`foldl'` and `foldr'` are different.

```
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl' f z0 xs = foldr f' id xs z0
  where f' x k z = k $! f z x
```

At every step of reduction, the argument is evaluated first and then the function application, the tree will be traversed i.e. O(n) best case performance.